# Can I convert 5v 20mA to 12v 7a

Tags: design, converter

I want to convert the 5v 20mA power from a digital Arduino output to a strong enough power for a 12v 7a motor. I do not believe the converter (linked below) I have selected will do the full extent of what I need. Are there any converters out there to fulfill my needs? Or should I just use a 12v 7a power supply?

Comment: You didn't link this converter you mention, but no, you can't. Such a device would violate conservation of energy.

Comment: You may need to add a flux capacitor to your circuit for that. I think people usually look for the (expensive) 1.21GW version, but I guess a 100W-200W version will be sufficient in this case since there is no time travel or DeLoreans involved. (12V x 7A = 84W)

Comment: No, you would use your Arduino output as the control signal for a supply that powers the motor.

Answer (score 3):

While others have pointed out the obvious conservation of energy, this might be an innocent x-y problem

An Arduino can only output 5V with a drive strength of 20mA  (10mA for safety). This is obviously no good for directly driving anything other than an LED or another chip. What it can be used for is to drive something that can control 12V which could sink 7A ... a MOSFET for instance

Answer (score 0):

If you can pull this off, you will be wealthy beyond dreams of avarice.  You're proposing putting 0.1W into your converter and pulling 84W out, implying that most of your output power came from whole cloth.  If you had 20A available on your 5V supply this would be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. Since there is law called conservation of energy.
$$ 5 \times 20 \times 10^{-3} = 0.1W $$
$$ 12 \times 7 = 84W $$

You need a 84W supply to run the motor.